# reference a VisualForce component attribute to use in itself

Tags: apex, visualforce, visualforce-component

I would like to know how to get an attribute of a component in a visualForce code.

In this code, wrappers is a map and I would like to put the value of the pageBlocktable to a List which is contained in my map, it is accessible by the key "cable".
Unfortunately, when I try to hardcode the value I want in the get function with a string, I have an error.

I have tried to replace what is is the circle pointed by the arrow with :

```
Cable
"Cable"
'Cable'
\"Cable\"
\'Cable\'
```

But none of them seem function, so I tried to get it by putting in a title and acces it later.

I also dont think it is possible to use the apex:param to set the variable of my controller and reference it.

Can someone help me getting the right synthax or tell me how to achieve what I am trying to do?

thanks

[image: visualForce code]

Comment: welcome to SFSE!  Please see [ask] on getting the most from the Community. Please don't use screen shots - instead, [edit] and paste your VF markup (minimum set) and format using the toolbar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference a component's attributes that way in Visualforce. You can only reference public Apex variables and methods, and Visualforce variables (e.g. from apex:pageBlockTable or apex:variable). As an aside, you only use `!` at the beginning of a merge field, and you don't use `.get` on a Map, but just the ordinary `map[key]` notation. `{wrappers[test.title]}` would have been the appropriate way to reference the value, if it were allowed.